# Blender 2.8 crashing on startup despite working mere minutes ago

Tags: error

I was using Blender 2.8 Beta fine, and then when I went to Edit > Preferences, is crashed. Now on startup, it spits this error and then immediately closes.

"al lib (EE) getchannelmap failed to match front-center channel (2) in channel map"

Getting this written down was a pain because of that. I tried deleting the preferences folder... and installing a different build of Blender 2.8, but it still won't start.

Comment: Did you use a surrounding sound configured in your computer? It seems like the sound library failed to configured your devices. Swap the sound output device to something else and try again might work, I guess

Comment: have you rebooted?

Comment: This happens to me when EeVee is Switched to Cycles etc. on Blender 2.80, which get's weirded-out with material normal map texture displacement on a sculpt and I see green speckles in the viewport with freezing and often a blue screen of death is also known to appear on high -end system with 20 cores and RTX 2080 Ti. Yes, Rebooting helps but is not the best solution to Blender 2.80 crashing initially.